# Android Vector Asset too big

Tags: android, android-studio, vector

I have an SVG that I'm using as the foreground for my adaptive icon. It's height and width are 128px128px. But when I go to drawable>New>Vector Asset and create an `XML` my `viewportWidth` is  disproportionately large.

My icon instead of being nested inside my background instead takes up the whole page and cover even the background. I tried using Inkscape and reduced the size of my SVG and sent it through drawable>New>Vector Asset again, but my icon is still gigantic, covering everything...but it's just a blurry blob.

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:width="128dp"
android:height="128dp"
android:viewportWidth="1280"
android:viewportHeight="1280">
```

Comment: Update your question with icon `layout.xml`

Comment: You can give it a try to use font for icons: https://android.jlelse.eu/font-awesome-a-better-way-to-display-symbols-and-icons-in-android-d694e5ee621f

Comment: Post your svg, rasterizing as image is a bad advise. And the part how you use it in your view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `SVG` for icon. Download the highest resolution **png** for your icon.
Then add that to your `minmap` directory. It will automatically generate icons of all sizes.

**Right click on minmap - > Image asset**

There you can position the icon

Comment: Cheers. Happy coding

Comment: Not recommended, since it does not solve the problem, but provides a workaround. `Using vector drawables instead of bitmaps reduces the size of your APK because the same file can be resized for different screen densities without loss of image quality. ` https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio

Comment: It's not a question of recommend. Vectors are harder to position and he tried using them.

Comment: @Arahasya not really, vectors as icons are as easy as 1,2,3. Just svg was not done properly and needs some modifications.

Comment: do u mean mipmap?

Answer (score 1):

When creating Vector from **`drawable>New>Vector Asset`** check **Override** option and put your desire size.

Comment: Didn't work. The Height and Width were at my desired size(108dp). But the viewportWidth & viewportHeight were still 1280

Comment: `viewportWidth` & `viewportHeight` are basically canvas width and height you are drawing. `width` and `height` define the default size of the Vector Drawable

Comment: @AbuYousuf works fine but unfortunately not for a batch import ! have to import and adjust 300 icons one by one like this.. ah GENIUS GOOOOGLEEEE!!!